# how to compare two different XML with all tags and show the difference?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jakarta-ee, xpath

Expected XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <bvoip:updateCustSiteDetailResponse xmlns:bvoip="http://dbor.att.com/bvoip/v1">
<bvoip:rowsAffected>13</bvoip:rowsAffected>
<bvoip:name>JAK</bvoip:name>
</bvoip:updateCustSiteDetailResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope><!-- P-V : 2016.10.21 -->
```

TargetXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns:updateCustSiteDetailResponse xmlns:ns="http://dbor.att.com/bvoip/v1">
      <ns:rowsAffected>14</ns:rowsAffected>
    </ns:updateCustSiteDetailResponse>  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Output 
    ------------
    Expected rowsAffected 13 but rowsAffected is 14
    Expected name is missing

Comment: The namespace is the same; why do you need to ignore it?

Comment: yes namespace is different bvoip vs ns , i need to compare only value with tags

Comment: That's a namespace **prefix**; the namespace for both prefixes is the same, `http://dbor.att.com/bvoip/v1`. Given that the namespaces are the same; why do you want to ignore it?

Comment: sry ignore the namespace prefix and my expected output as somthing like 
1) rowsAffected 13 but rowsAffected is 14
2) name is missing

Comment: and i did this in xmlUnit getting difference response like
[different] Expected number of child nodes '2' but was '1' - comparing <SOAP-ENV:Envelope...> at /Envelope[1] to <SOAP-ENV:Envelope...> at /Envelope[1]

Comment: Don't ignore it; _use it_. If you read the file with JAXP, for example, it will understand that they are the same element, i.e. `<{http://dbor.att.com/bvoip/v1}:updateCustSiteDetailResponse>`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options

a) Use a library like XMLUnit , get the differences and ignore the namespaces and compare text values

b) Rollout a difference comparator of your own. If there only a specific tag you need to compare (and you do not want additional dependencies or JAXP) you can use this approach.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws XPathExpressionException {
        String controlXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>  <SOAP-ENV:Body>    <bvoip:updateCustSiteDetailResponse xmlns:bvoip=\"http://dbor.att.com/bvoip/v1\"><bvoip:rowsAffected>13</bvoip:rowsAffected><bvoip:name>JAK</bvoip:name></bvoip:updateCustSiteDetailResponse>  </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
        String resultXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">  <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns:updateCustSiteDetailResponse xmlns:ns=\"http://dbor.att.com/bvoip/v1\">      <ns:rowsAffected>14</ns:rowsAffected>    </ns:updateCustSiteDetailResponse>  </SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
        String xPath = "//*[local-name()='rowsAffected']";
        XPath xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        Document controlDocument = getXMLDocument(controlXML);
        Document resultDocument = getXMLDocument(resultXML);
        Assert.assertEquals(xPathFactory.compile(xPath).evaluate(controlDocument),
                xPathFactory.compile(xPath).evaluate(resultDocument));

    }

    static private Document getXMLDocument(String xml) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document document = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return document;
    }
```

The above code fails the assertion as expected and gives me the result

```
Exception in thread "main" junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: The text nodes do not match expected:<1[3]> but was:<1[4]>
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:81)
    at org.ram.so.SOProject.XMLCompare.main(XMLCompare.java:26)
```

Comment: but tag will be dynamic here  String xPath = "//*[local-name()='rowsAffected']";

Comment: in the expected response

Comment: your answer is more useful to me ,, suppose the tag Expected response <bvoip:rollnumber>155</bvoip:rollnumber>

Comment: targetXML as  <ns:rollnumber>14</ns:rowsnumber>... it will be dynamic depends upon request ..